# trying to disable laptop keyboard using gpedit.msc

Tags: keyboard

Water was spilled on my laptop keyboard, and now most keys dont work, while other keys just stick and input the key continuously. I've purchased a usb keyboard, but now im trying to disable the keyboard of my laptop.

I found this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard) explaining how to disable the keyboard using gpedit.msc, but my version of windows doesn't have it so I had to download a gpedit.msc file [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/)

I got gpedit.msc working, but when I go to edit the Device Installation settings as listed in the first answer on how to use gpedit.msc, the option isn't there. There's no option for Device Installation in Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->System.

I'm pretty stuck. I also tried downloading DevCon, but when i run DevCon it just pops up the command prompt window for a split second and then it closes. I'm really lost, help!

Comment: If you open the Device Manager, what do you see listed under the keyboard category?

Comment: sorry I didn't see these suggestions, I'm sort of new to Stack Exchange. Thanks for all your advice. I ended up just taking the keyboard out and unplugging it from the motherboard until my new keyboard arrived.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to "Device Manager" accessible through many ways, including (at least Windows 7) right-clicking "My Computer" and selecting "Manage"

[image: Screenshot of Windows 7 Computer Management showing the left panel which is the menu hierarchy, and the middle panel with the main options.]

On the left side of the window is a hierarchical menu-- navigate down to "Device Manager."

In the middle panel, expand "Keyboards" and see if you can find one with the laptop manufacturer's name, or some other clearly-the-keyboard-in-question properties.

Right-click one and look for the option "disable." Now, you may not have that option (I only have one keyboard, and it probably doesn't let you disable your only keyboard!), but try it out and let us know how it goes.

Comment: there is no option to disable it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0YTaD.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the answer [provided here?](https://superuser.com/questions/361641/disabling-a-laptop-keyboard-in-place-of-a-usb-keyboard)

What I would do is:

1) Download Devcon.exe and put the exe in your path

2) Find your keyboard by running `devcon find * | findstr /i "keyboard"` from the command line. Note the resource ID for the keyboard you want to disable.

3) Run `devcon disable <res_ID>` where res_ID is the resource ID you got in step 2.

You could script that, and if you need assistance, let me know. But I believe that once you disable a device, it should stay disabled until re-enabled.

Hope that helps!